# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found||pywraplp

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to implement MILP using python 3.7 on Windows 10.Installed `ortools` using pip
`import ortools` is working perfectly OK but 
`from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp` throwing error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried installing installing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2019?

Here is the download [link](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe)

Solved the issue for me.

Hope it helps!
Best from Vienna